# Batch File Logging Issues

Tags: logging, batch-file

how to get the logs of a batch file while getting the output on screen as well.

Note my batch file takes several input as well, I tried fair bit of things but its not working, does anyone have some simple solution ?

Comment: You should look at [asynchronous Tee program](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=26319&sid=22467c0d3f402eae9371ccd6eca39b78#p26319) by Aacini.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use a TEE technique.

```
:Tee <Message> <File>
echo(%1
echo(%1>>%2
exit /b 0
```

Use like this

```
call :Tee "This is my Message to display in the log and on screen." "Output.txt"
```

Replace your `echo` commands with `call :Tee` commands

Answer (score 0):

```
set LogFile=somepath\logfile.txt
set logg=^> _^&^& type _^&^&type _^>^>%LogFile%
echo this goes to screen AND file! %logg%
```

This is a bit tricky. So let's disassemble that line to four parts:

```
set logg=      ^> _          ^&type _           ^&type _^>^>%LogFile%
```

The Idea is to print the line to a temporary file (named "_") (second part) then type the contents of that file to screen (third part) then type it to the logfile (fourth part).

Put that all to a variable (first part), so you don't have to type that monsterstring to every line. (this is the reason why the ">" and "&" are escaped with "^")

So every time you use

```
echo whatever %logg%
```

it will appear on the screen AND write to %logfile%

This also works with commands:

```
ipconfig %logg%
```