# Batch scripting, log everything

Tags: batch-file, logging, cmd

I have written a tool and I would like it to continue outputting to the cmd.exe screen. However I want to also output everything to a log file.

In short I want to output to both the cmd.exe screen and a log file, how could I go about doing this?

Thanks, Michael

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17455690/2152082) [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31324795/2152082)

Comment: here you have native windows implementation of `tee` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711839/using-a-custom-tee-command-for-bat-file/10719322#10719322  and here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21841567/388389

Comment: Try the following [Link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php)

Comment: I cannot install any other software, only use batch. Also, I want to output everything that is shown in dos to a log file, there must be an easier way than appending everything with > log123.txt?